# How to check if object exists (Selenium/Python) and execute if-else

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to create script in order to automate order entry. I'm struggling with client search results. I wrote following if statement:

```
# checks if there are any search results
if browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='nclk']"):

    # creates variable with all search results
    searchCount = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='nclk']") 

    # counts search results
    searchCountCheck = len(searchCount) 
    ...
```

It looks for `"a[class='nclk']"`, because if there are any search results, this object exists. The problem is that when there are none, it stops the script with an error message `...unable to locate element...` - it doesn't go to else statement and I have no idea how to sort it.

I know that it could be done by `try:` but the problem is that there are many statements nested inside those two so it would end up as a huge mess.

I think that the best way to deal with this issue would be to create a try statement that checks if such object exists and it creates variable (which value depends on existence of the object)- but i don't know how to write it and how to pass the variable to following if-else statements.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://seleniumwebdrivertrainings.com/how-to-check-if-an-element-exist-with-webdriver/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
# if result is 0, then there is no element matching.
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#element')
```

in this case you don't have to add `try`, because if there is no element, the list will have a length 0 and don't throw any error. In your case it would be something like this:

```
if (browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='nclk']")):
  searchCount = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='nclk']")
  searchCountCheck = len(searchCount)
```

Comment: if i use just 'browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='nclk']")' then it just gives me error message and stops executing script even though it should go to else statement and do all things defined there- instead- it just stops.

Comment: Yes, but I suggest you to use `find_elements_by` not `find_element_by`

Comment: Cheers mate! One 's' changes everything :). Once again thank you!

Comment: `find_elements_by` gives a list out, and if the list is empty `if` statement will return `false`

Comment: @ugabuga77 no problem. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT :

I forgot that `find_elements_by_xpath()` returns an empty or non-empty list, but this solution would be good for the various `find_element_by_*` functions.

---

What you could do is use a [try-except-else](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) statement. For instance,

```
try:
    searchCount = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[class='nclk']")
    searchCountCheck = len(searchCount)
except NoSuchElementException: 
    print("No element found. Breaking...")
except: 
    print("Generic error message.")
else:
    # Do stuff with searchCount / searchCountCheck / etc.
```

The `else` portion is only entered if no errors are thrown in the `try` portion.

Answer (score 0):

you can set searchCountCheck to 0 after exception.

```
try:
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='nclk']")
    searchCount = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='nclk']")
    searchCountCheck = len(searchCount)
    flag = 1
except NoSuchElementException:
    searchCountCheck = 0
    flag = 0
```

> find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector) Finds an element by css
>   selector.
>
> Args:  css_selector - CSS selector string, ex: ‘a.nav#home’ Returns:
>   WebElement - the element if it was found Raises:
>   NoSuchElementException - if the element wasn’t found Usage:    element =
>   driver.find_element_by_css_selector(‘#foo’)

Comment: Is there a way to use 'try:' method to create variable and assign to it value depending on existence of this element? So say if element exists var check gets 1, if not it gets 0 and then I pass this var (and its assigned value) to if- else statement?